# Dialog box using fragment shows error

Tags: android

I have just started implementing the DialogFragment in Android and got stuck since it is throwing an error that i'm posting here with other java files.

error:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cisystem3.dialogfragment, PID: 3519
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding contentvat com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:302)                                                                                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233)
 at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
 at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2077)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:922)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is my DialogFragment onCreateDialog method

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("My Dialog Box");
        builder.setMessage("Do you like this dialog");
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();

        return dialog;
    }
```

MainActivity click Listener

```
  btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
                BlankFragment myFragment=new BlankFragment();
                myFragment.show(manager,"My Dialog");
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to show alert dialog, don't use dialog fragment. Dialog Fragment is used when you want to show your custom layout.

Comment: In developer site ie https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html they havn't mentioned anything

Comment: what are all the code written in your `onCreateDialog()`, you can directly do that from activity. Why Extra Dialog Fragment

Comment: Doing some workarround about DialogFragment...So i went to developer site and trying to implement the DialogFragment as they mentioned over there...

Comment: try http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-dialog-fragment-example or  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html

Comment: Thanks...I found the mistake i have written both onCreateDialog where i'm trying to do call basic Alert Dialog and also i have called onCreateView where m Custom Dialog appears..When comment the onCreateView my code starts working...Dont know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this function in your MainActivity

```
private void openDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("My Dialog Box");
    builder.setMessage("Do you like this dialog");
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

And then call it as below

```
btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDialog();
        }
    });
```

You don't need the DialogFragment. Remove the DialogFragment code entirely.